# X11. Symbol not found: _CGLGetCurrentContext

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, x11, dlib

I try to use dlib in Qt console app on OS X. So except another lines(which I removed for tests) my .pro file looks like:

```
LIBS += -L/opt/X11/lib -lX11
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/X11/include
```

Output when I run the application:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _CGLGetCurrentContext   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL  in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo

How can I solve this?

**UPD:**
.pro file:

```
QT       += core
CONFIG   += console

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = dlibOSX

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ../../../Downloads/dlib-19.0/dlib/all/source.cpp

LIBS += -L/Users/user/Downloads/dlib-19.0/examples/build/dlib_build

INCLUDEPATH += /Users/user/Downloads/dlib-19.0
LIBS += -L/Users/user/Downloads/dlib-19.0 

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.23/include /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.23/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib -ljpeg -lpng -ljpeg -lz


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13/lib

QT += opengl

LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT -DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT
```

Error:

> nativefont.h:27: error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need console application - why are you linking X11?

```
QT       += core 
CONFIG   += console
```

After that hello world should work

If you are using OpenGL functions from your application - add

```
QT += opengl
```

**UPD:** (updated question answers)

1) Here is an error:

> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT **-DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT**

Should be -**DD**LIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT

2) If you need X11/Xlib.h - install XQuartz (for OSX) or libx11-dev (Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for you response. Indeed, but when I try to exclude X11 libs and headers then I get compiler error `error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found`. Also please check **UPD** section in my question.

Comment: @don-prog, updated answer after your question is updated

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake... And regarding to XQuartz: I installed XQuartz from [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) and rebuild dlib and my application but still get an error `Symbol not found: _CGLGetCurrentContext`, maybe I need to change something in my pro file?

Comment: unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH may help

Comment: @Evgeniy Indeed - thanks for the tip - works - as per https://lists.macports.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2010-August/012631.html ! :)

Comment: @Evgeniy PS An answer looking for a more general question?